# django use default login on root url itself

Tags: python, django

my urls.py file contails

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from users import views
from users.forms import PickyAuthenticationForm
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}),    
    url(r'^terms-conditions/', 'users.views.terms_view', name='terms_view'),)
```

in my setting.py file

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/terms_view/'
LOGIN_URL = ''
```

my login template contains

```
    {% extends "base-users.html" %}
<!--{% load staticfiles %}-->

{% block title %}<title>Sign In</title>{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form action="." method='POST' class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">   
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
{{ form.username.errors }} {{ form.password.errors }}
</form>
```

{% endblock content %}

Am not getting any error the page is still in same location . Why the form is not submitting.

Comment: Is the form supposed to use a `GET` request (probably not, since the CSRF token gets exposed)? Because the `<form>` tag is otherwise missing a `method='POST'` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I missed that but . the field has some data on submitting but the error says This field is required.

Comment: See Rajesh's answer below: Your input fields have ids, but no names.

Answer (score 0):

The fields are attributes of the form, not standalone variables. You should do:

```
{{ form.username.errors }} {{ form.password.errors }}
```

**Edit**

You have also missed off the `name` attribute on the forms themselves. Without that the browser cannot submit any data for the fields.

```
<form name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="..." required>
```

Really though, you should be using the Django form itself to render the fields:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    {{ form.username }}
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed that . Still having the same problem. Am not getting the errors too

Comment: Now I got the error . but it says every time This field is required.  event if it has some data

Answer (score 0):

> Please set the action and method attribute of the form element and
>   check it,I think it will work.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="." method='POST' class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="emailField" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">   
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="passwordField" placeholder="Enter password" required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    {{ username.errors }} {{ password.errors }}
    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: I have changed that in my question too. the field has some data on submitting but the error says This field is required.

Comment: Can you specify which field getting error in terminal?

Comment: Hello, now check my post, I have put name attribute to input field,now check it , it will work sure.